# How to remove the shadow of a button on Xamarin Forms

Tags: button, xamarin.forms, shadow

is it possible?
I would like to remove the shadow of the buttons on Xamarin Forms.

Thanks

Comment: i guess you could just rework the template ...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For delete shadow on button Android you just need create a renderer in project Droid and set BackroundColor with transparent or other color.

For a project using PCL :

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Button),typeof(FlatButtonRenderer))]
namespace Project.Droid
    {
        public class FlatButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
        {
            protected override void OnDraw(Android.Graphics.Canvas canvas)
            {
                base.OnDraw(canvas);
            }
        }
    }
```

In XAML :

```
<Button BackgroundColor="Transparent" Text="ClickMe"/>
```

Comment: Incredible, i just created that class and the borders works and shadows was removed on android. Tks.

Comment: How to do this for shared project?

Answer (score 6):

Explaining with more detail.

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using ProjectName.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Button), typeof(FlatButtonRenderer))]
namespace ProjectName.Droid
{    
    public class FlatButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnDraw(Android.Graphics.Canvas canvas)
        {
            base.OnDraw(canvas);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can derive a new type of button. And only apply it to that button

Answer (score 1):

@Tonatio in your renderer instead of using

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Button), typeof(FlatButtonRenderer))]
```

use this

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(YourCustomButton), typeof(FlatButtonRenderer))]
```

you will have to make a CustomButton control that inherits from **Xamarin.Forms.Button** and then use that custom button in your xaml instead of regular button. that should do the thing

```
     //Add references to your custom control
        xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:YourNameSpace.Controls"
     //Use control
     <Grid>
           <controls:YourCustomButton x:Name="_customButton"/>
     </Grid>
```

Feel free to drop by if you need some more help.

Answer (score 1):

You can now just set the Visual to Default instead of Material and that fixed it for me:

```
<Button 
Visual="Default"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple hack around this. Simply wrap the button in a `Frame` element, with `HasShadow` set to `False`

```
<Frame HasShadow="False" Padding="0" Margin="0">
    <Button Padding="15"
            Text="Log in"
            TextColor="Blue"
            FontSize="17" />
</Frame>
```

This will remove the button's shadow

Comment: This hack doesnt work.