# Xamarin update changes the general ui look, how to get back to the old look

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, themes

Xamarin.Android Version = 8.2.0.15

Xamarin Version = 4.9.0.749

Xamarin Forms Version = 2.5.0.280555

So right after updating to last version of Xamarin
My app is not looking the way it used to be.
For example I now have shadow under buttons and [this link did not helped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38478596/how-to-remove-the-shadow-of-a-button-on-xamarin-forms)
I'm right now messing with Project.Droid.Resources.values.Styles but it is not helping either

My Question is how can I get back to the "Default Android theme", get rid of shadows under buttons and make the ui object look like it did before?

Not to mention IOS project is looking FINE as always :-)

Comment: Try removing the Android theme set of your project. You are most likely pulling in an AppCompat theme that adds Material Design styling to default views.

Comment: Thanks for the comment,

 I checked the manifest which do not specify any theme and I even removed the inherited theme for the splash screen [Some screenshots](https://imgur.com/gallery/TJHHK) which did not made any change.

But I did a ctrl+maj+f "AppCompat" found I have a nugget called Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat
and also a all bunch of constant with AppCompat/AppCompat_Light in their names their are all located in the Project/Resources/Resource.designer.cs
I don't even know what is this file for....

Could these be the source problem?