# Remove shadow from Android Button built in Xamarin forms

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I am trying to get rid of the shadow that is being displayed at the bottom of a button in android built using xamarin forms. I have tried all that I could. But I have not achieved it.
I have attached an image for reference. 
I request your'l to help me and put me out of my misery.
Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove the shadow of a button on Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38478596/how-to-remove-the-shadow-of-a-button-on-xamarin-forms)

Answer (score 1):

1) Create custom control and derive it from Button.

```
   public class ButtonWithoutShadow : Button
 {
 }
```

2) Create custom renderer

```
 [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ButtonWithoutShadow), typeof(ButtonWithoutShadowRenderer))]
public class ButtonWithoutShadowRenderer : ButtonRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {
            Control.Elevation = 0;
        }

    }
}
```

3) In xaml page use this button:

```
<controls:ButtonWithoutShadow TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="185" HeightRequest="52" BackgroundColor="#ffcd00" Font="Roboto-Regular" FontSize="23" Text="Поиск" BorderRadius="0" BorderWidth="0" />
```

Comment: Alternatively, if you want every `Button` in your project not to have a shadow, mark your custom renderer as such:

`[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Button), typeof(ButtonWithoutShadowRenderer))]`

Answer (score 0):

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Button),typeof(FlatButtonRenderer))]

namespace Project.Droid

 {
        public class FlatButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
        {
            protected override void OnDraw(Android.Graphics.Canvas canvas)
            {
                base.OnDraw(canvas);
            }
        }
    }

<Button BackgroundColor="Transparent" Text="ClickMe"/>
```

Source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/39966574/7794690

Comment: I don't want the background color to be transparent. It has to be white on a blue background.

Answer (score 0):

For me, only thing that removed the shadow was doing this in a custom button render:

```
Control.StateListAnimator = null;
```

It may be dependent on API level, though, so might also require:

```
Control.Elevation = 0;
```