# How to remove the animation/shadow effect when an android button is tapped on Xamarin Forms Platform

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

[image]    [image]

I need to remove the shadow that appears when my android buttons are tapped from xamarin forms. ( shown in the above pic. when yes and no are originally same colored. when no is pressed, a shadow is cast upon it causing its color to be darker)

I followed the examples stated in 
[How to remove the shadow of a button on Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38478596/how-to-remove-the-shadow-of-a-button-on-xamarin-forms)
but as my button color is supposed to be red, I did not change the background color in the PCL to red. But the shadows still appear on the android button when tapped.

Then, I followed this link :
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/122752/removing-shadow-from-android-buttons
but the shadow on my button still exists too. I think just like what is stated in the link, since my xamarin forms version is 2.5.0.280555, the solution they provided will not work.

Does anyone have any advice or solutions on what I can possibly do if I need to remove the android button shadow  when tapped on my Xamarin.Forms project if i am still required to keep my xamarin forms version as 2.5.0.280555?

It says here that the issue has been resolved in a later build :
https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/1954

So I upgraded to 2.5.1.52 for xamarin forms.
But I still see the shadow on the button when it is tapped on a android platform.

My Code changes are as follow:
In Style.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">    
    </style>
    <!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
    <style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
<item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/NoShadowButton</item>

    </style>
<style name="NoShadowButton" parent="android:style/Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:stateListAnimator">@null</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And i even implemented a custom renderer

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(FlatButton), typeof(UnanimatedButtonRenderer))]
namespace RideNow.Droid
{
  public class UnanimatedButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
    {

        protected override void OnDraw(Android.Graphics.Canvas canvas)
        {
            base.OnDraw(canvas);
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (this.Control != null && this.Element != null)
            {
                var nativeButton = (Android.Widget.Button)Control;
                nativeButton.SetShadowLayer(0, 0, 0, Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);

                nativeButton.Elevation = 0;
                if (this.CheckIsCustomFont())
                {
                    var typeFace = this.GetTypeFace();
                    var typeFaceStyle = this.GetTypeFaceStyle();
                    if (typeFace != null)
                    {
                        nativeButton.SetTypeface(typeFace, typeFaceStyle);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where Flatbutton is just a custom button inheriting from button of xamarin forms without any add ons. But nothing seems to be working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following in your custom renderer:

```cs
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (this.Control != null && e.NewElement != null)
        {
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt > BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
            {
                this.Control.StateListAnimator = null;
            }
            else
            {
                this.Control.Elevation = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's what I see on an Android 6 emulator:

[image]

---

If you want absolutely no color change on click, you could customize the renderer further:

```cs
public class UnanimatedButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
{
    private FlatButton TypedElement => this.Element as FlatButton;

    public UnanimatedButtonRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (this.Control != null && e.NewElement != null)
        {
            this.UpdateBackground();

            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt > BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
            {
                this.Control.StateListAnimator = null;
            }
            else
            {
                this.Control.Elevation = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        if (e.PropertyName.Equals(VisualElement.BackgroundColorProperty.PropertyName) ||
            e.PropertyName.Equals(Button.CornerRadiusProperty.PropertyName) ||
            e.PropertyName.Equals(Button.BorderWidthProperty.PropertyName))
        {
            this.UpdateBackground();
        }
    }

    private void UpdateBackground()
    {
        if (this.TypedElement != null)
        {
            using (var background = new GradientDrawable())
            {
                background.SetColor(this.TypedElement.BackgroundColor.ToAndroid());
                background.SetStroke((int)Context.ToPixels(this.TypedElement.BorderWidth), this.TypedElement.BorderColor.ToAndroid());
                background.SetCornerRadius(Context.ToPixels(this.TypedElement.CornerRadius));

                // customize the button states as necessary
                using (var backgroundStates = new StateListDrawable())
                {
                    backgroundStates.AddState(new int[] { }, background);

                    this.Control.SetBackground(backgroundStates);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the code above, the background is being set for all states, but it can be customized.  For example,

```cs
// set a background for the un-pressed state
backgroundStates.AddState(new int[] { -Android.Resource.Attribute.StatePressed }, background);

// set a background for the pressed state
backgroundStates.AddState(new int[] { Android.Resource.Attribute.StatePressed }, backgroundPressed);
```

Comment: Tried but it doesn't seem to work. :( The dark shadow effect still appears when i press and hold on the android button

Comment: Thank alot its working now. But is it possible for you to explain what this portion of code is doing ? Is it resetting the background state or something?
                using (var backgroundStates = new StateListDrawable())
                {
                    backgroundStates.AddState(new int[] { }, background);

                    this.Control.SetBackground(backgroundStates);
                }